# Git rebasing over files

Tags: git, rebase

I have a project I have been working on and want to share as a nice code example. I have been keeping the code and proprietary images in a separate branch but made the mistake of committing some copy righted material to the public repo.

I need to remove the images from the history of the project and would prefer to not damage any of the other commits =/

How can I surgicaly remove files from the git history tree while damaging as little of the history as possible?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.

http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/